# Thread does not abort on application closing

Tags: c#, multithreading, terminate, abort, interruption

I have an application which does some background task (network listening & reading) in a separate `Thread`. It seems however that the Thread is not being Terminated/Aborted when I close the application (click "x" button on titlebar).
Is that because the main Thread routine is `while(true) {...}` ?
What is the solution here? I was looking for some "interruption" flag for the Thread as the condition for "while" loop, but didn't found any.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The simplest way is to set the [IsBackground](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground.aspx) property of the thread to true. This will prevent it from keeping the application open. An application terminates when all non-background threads terminate.

A more controlled way to stop the thread is to send it a message to shut down cleanly and ensure that it has terminated before letting your main thread terminate.

A method that I wouldn't recommend is to call [`Thread.Abort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty8d3wta.aspx). This has a number of problems, one of which is that it is not guaranteed to terminate the thread. From the documentation:

> Calling this method **usually** terminates the thread.

Emphasis mine.

Comment: +1 to the message method. `while (stayAlive)` instead of `true` is much cleaner, even if it potentially takes a few extra seconds for the loop to clear up.

Answer (score 4):

You can always force the issue:

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // ... do stuff
        Environment.Exit(Environment.ExitCode);
    }
}
```

The better approach is to set the Thread.IsBackground property to true as Mark already mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

You could improve the while(true) loop to

```
void DoWork() {
    while(!ShouldIQuitManualResetEvent.WaitOne(0)) {
      // do something
    }
    IDidQuitManualResetEvent.Set()
}
```

A bit more graceful, short from the identifier names.

Answer (score 0):

Well, instead of `while(true)`, maybe you should:

```
while(appIsRunning)
{
}
```

And, at the closing event for your form,

```
appIsRunning = false;
thread.Join(2000);
```

where the last line is just to make sure you wait for the thread to cleanly finish. There are many other ways to force an end to a thread, but the problem is just there: you don't want to be *forcing* things, you want them to happen as naturally as possible.

After the join, you can check the status of thread to see if it has finished. If it doesn't, **then** (and only then) force its finish with a abort, and maybe notify your user (or write a log record) that something has not ended the way it should.

Comment: Yes, but do remember to use `volatile` or `lock` or some other method of synchronization.

Comment: @Mark: might be totally wrong here, but since the child Thread only reads and the main Thread only writes, is there a chance for a bug?

Comment: Without synchronizing it is not guaranteed that a change to appIsRunning from one thread will be visible in the other thread. You can read more here: http://timl.net/2009/03/volatile-memory.html

Answer (score 0):

You can start your thread as:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(DoStuff, input)
```

And it will be abort automatically with application close.